# Configure AWS DataPipeline

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

I am facing issue while configuring DataPipeline. I am getting the following error.

```
ERROR: Invalid role 'DataPipelineDefaultRole' in slot 'role'. Please make sure that the role exist and Data Pipeline has permission to assume the role.
```

I already configured data pipeline permission as per the standard procedure.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-iam-roles.html

Comment: have you found any fix for this?

Comment: @AsfarIrshad No, my friend, I left it there and switch other things since it was kind of blocker for me.

Answer (score 1):

> I solved this issue by creating DataPipelineDefaultRole and
> DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole and granting necessary permissions
> which will be used by data pipeline

More details https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-iam-roles.html